# Update wizard disappears after pressing next button and I can't update model from database

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, entity

Update wizard disappears after pressing next button and I can't update model from database. I can't select new added table to my database.  [Update wizard showing me this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvrbE.png)

I need to add the new table to my diagram page or to the `.edmx` file.

Comment: Open the VS Server Explorer and delete all of the Data Connections, then in the EF update wizard add a known good connection string. That solved the problem for me. Sorry I don't have a reference to the post that suggested this solution.